# Run a Infinite Running Background Task with Xamarin.Forms on Android

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin

My problem is the following:

I am trying to run a infinite background task in a service , which should start on bootup on Android. (This task is for checking frequently a json file on a website for changes.) Apparently, running a task in a background service (which has been executed by a BroadcastReceiver) isnt possible, **because the thread seems to wait endless for the UI; So only when the UI is launched, this task will run.**

This is what happens in logcat when I try this:

```
Waited long enough for ServiceRecord <Name of Service>
```

Running something outside the task works, but inside not.
So: Is there a possible way to do something like this:

- Run a BroadcastReceiver on BOOT_COMPLETED
- Run a Service inside the BroadcastReceiver
- Start a infinite Task app-independent

Service

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using <MyPackage>.services;

namespace <MyPackage>.Droid
{
    [Service]
    public class BackgroundService : Service
    {
        CancellationTokenSource _cts;

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
            _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            Task.Run(() => {
                try
                {
                    //Invoke Task
                    var process = new BackgroundDataWatcher();
                    process.StartWatcherAsync(_cts.Token).Wait();
                }
                catch (Android.OS.OperationCanceledException)
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        var message = new CancelledMessage();
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
                            () => MessagingCenter.Send(message, "CancelledMessage")
                        );
                    }
                }

            }, _cts.Token);
            StartForeground((int)NotificationFlags.ForegroundService, new Notification(Resource.Drawable.notification," ist aktiv..."));
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            if (_cts != null)
            {
                _cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                _cts.Cancel();
            }
            base.OnDestroy();
        }
    }

    public class CancelledMessage{}
}
```

Receiver

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using static <MyPackage>.services.BackgroundDataWatcher;
using Android.Util;

namespace <MyPackage>.Droid
{
    [BroadcastReceiver]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
    public class StartReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        private static int notificationId = 0;
        private static String TAG = "StartReceiver";
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Log.Info(TAG,"Receiver started!");
            Log.Info(TAG,"Adding NotificationMessage");
            //Register Service for Notifications.

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<NotificationMessage>(this, "NotificationMessage", message => {
                    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
                    .SetContentTitle(message.Header)
                    .SetContentText(message.Message)
                    .SetAutoCancel(message.IsRemoveable)
                    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.notification);
                    if (message.InformUser)
                        builder.SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.All);

                    // Build the notification:
                    Notification notification = builder.Build();

                    // Get the notification manager:
                    NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

                    // Publish the notification:
                    notificationId++;
                    notificationManager.Notify(message.Notificationid != 0 ? message.Notificationid : notificationId, notification);

            });
            Log.Info(TAG,"Creating intent.");
            Intent timerIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(BackgroundService));
            timerIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            timerIntent.SetAction("ReminderService.ACTION_RESCHEDULE");
            Log.Info(TAG,"Start Service.");
            context.StartService(timerIntent);
            Log.Info(TAG,"All done");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your code is right. And you just need to keep the service alive as the app-independent background task. 'return StartCommandResult.Sticky;' will keep the service alive. you have written it in the service. But the user need open the app at the beginning. If use never open the app the Broadcast will never start.

Comment: @Sebastian G., any luck getting this to work?

Comment: Not really. Dropped that Project For a while.